# Additive and multiplicative identities of a semiring can coincide.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, semiring

Semiring $(S, \oplus, \otimes, \bar{0}, \bar{1})$ is an algebraic structure in which  $(S, \oplus, \otimes)$ is a monoid and  $(S, \otimes, \bar{1})$ is a semigroup and multiplication $\otimes$ distributes over addition $\oplus$. In general, it is noted that $\bar{0}\neq \bar{1}$ (except in case of monosemiring). I have a following counter example of a non- monosemiring in which $\bar{0}= \bar{1}$.

Let $S$ be the set of all simple undirected graphs. Then the structure $(S, \cup, \nabla, (\emptyset,  \emptyset))$ is a semiring  in which the empty graph $(\emptyset,  \emptyset)$ is a neutral element with respect to both addition $\cup$ (graph union) and multiplication $\nabla$ (graph join). That is, in this case additive and multiplicative identity of the semiring coincides. This semiring is very similar to **max- plus semiring** except that $\bar{0}=\bar{1}$ here.

I look forward for any suggestions/agreement or disagreement to the above statement.

Comment: Why do you claim that $F \mathbin{\nabla} (G \cup H)$ is the same graph as $(F \mathbin{\nabla} G) \cup (F \mathbin{\nabla} H)$? That seems wrong to me; in particular, the first graph is connected and the second is not. If we take $F = G = H = K_1$, then the $F \mathbin{\nabla} (G \cup H)$ is $P_3$ and $(F \mathbin{\nabla} G) \cup (F \mathbin{\nabla} H)$ is $2 P_2$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov By the ways, please let me know what are $K_1$, $P_3$ and $2P_2$ here?

Comment: @MishaLavrov If the first graph is connected,  the second graph must also be connected by definition of $\cup$ because of the graph $F$ being common in both the components.

Comment: Oh, I see - your graph union is not disjoint union, but keeps track of the vertex set. (My notation: $K_1$ is the $1$-vertex graph, $P_3$ the path on $3$ vertices, and $2P_2$ two copies of the path on $2$ vertices.) In that case, how do you define the graph join when the vertex sets overlap?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes it is not disjoint union. When vertex sets overlap,  we would have self loops, but we defined the graph join in such a way that self loops are disregarded (or a self loop is the same as a singleton vertex).